# Is the all( ) function related to the for( ) function in R?

Tags: r, function, for-loop

I was given a task of creating a function that checks if a natural number is prime or not without the use of the for() function. That I solved by defining a "set" and using the all() function.

```
prime <- function(nat){
  N <- 1:(nat-1)
  N <- N[-c(1,nat)]
  if(!isTRUE(all(nat%%N != 0))){
    return(paste(nat,"is a prime number."))
  }else{
    return(paste(nat,"is not a prime number."))
  }
}
#Assuming the input is actually a natural number. Error response is not my issue.
```

Now, my question is if the all() function is actually not a for() "in disguise". It is basically doing the same task the for() function would have done. Checking the logical statement of nat%%N != 0 for each member of my "set". I'm not an expert, but it seems to me that the all() function is a for() function for logical values and therefore, their inner workings must be very similar.

If someone could provide clarification as to whether the all() function works in the same way as a for() function or not I would appreciate it. Can the all() be considered a for() function?

Comment: That is not correct. Its like saying `sum(1:10)` is a for loop in disguise. Just to let you know, R is a vectorized language meaning that most of the functions work with vectors. Tht does not mean they are for loops in disguise. It just means you do not have to write a for loop because the function CONTAINS one. so NO `all` is not a for loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In one sense, any function that operates on a vector of length greater than 1 can be represented as a `for` loop. For example, consider `sum()`, which computes the sum of the elements of the given vector. It could be represented as the following:

```r
sum <- function(x) {
  s <- 0
  for (i in x) s <- s + i
  s
}
```

Indeed, in the C code underlying R, it my actually be represented in this way. Do you consider `sum()` to be a `for` loop? If not, `all()` can be represented as a sum:

```r
all <- function(x) {
  sum(as.logical(x)) == length(x)
}
```

It is clearly not a `for` loop in this case. If your assignment is to avoid using the `for` function, then anything you write that avoids `for` should be fine.